# Linear Regression Lasagne / Theano

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, theano, lasagne

I'm trying to make a simple multivariate linear Regression with Lasagne.
This is my Input:

```
x_train = np.array([[37.93, 139.5, 329., 16.64,
                    16.81, 16.57, 1., 707.,
                    39.72, 149.25, 352.25, 16.61,
                    16.91, 16.60, 40.11, 151.5,
                    361.75, 16.95, 16.98, 16.79]]).astype(np.float32)
y_train = np.array([37.92, 138.25, 324.66, 16.28, 16.27, 16.28]).astype(np.float32)
```

For this two data points the network should be able to learn `y` perfectly.

Here is the model:

```
i1 = T.matrix()
y = T.vector()
lay1 = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(None,20),input_var=i1)
out1 = lasagne.layers.get_output(lay1)
lay2 = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(lay1, 6, nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.linear)
out2 = lasagne.layers.get_output(lay2)
params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(lay2, trainable=True)
cost = T.sum(lasagne.objectives.squared_error(out2, y))
grad = T.grad(cost, params)
updates = lasagne.updates.sgd(grad, params, learning_rate=0.1) 
f_train = theano.function([i1, y], [out1, out2, cost], updates=updates)
```

After executing multiple times

```
f_train(x_train,y_train)
```

the cost explodes to infinity. Any idea what is going wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The network has too much capacity for a single training instance. You would need to apply some strong regularization to prevent the training diverging. Alternatively, and hopefully more realistically, give it more complex training data (many instances).

With a single instance the task can be solved using just one input, instead of 20, and with the `DenseLayer`'s bias disabled:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import lasagne
import theano.tensor as T


def compile():
    x, z = T.matrices('x', 'z')
    lh = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(None, 1), input_var=x)
    ly = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(lh, 6, nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.linear,
                                   b=None)
    y = lasagne.layers.get_output(ly)
    params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(ly, trainable=True)
    cost = T.sum(lasagne.objectives.squared_error(y, z))
    updates = lasagne.updates.sgd(cost, params, learning_rate=0.0001)
    return theano.function([x, z], [y, cost], updates=updates)


def main():
    f_train = compile()

    x_train = np.array([[37.93]]).astype(theano.config.floatX)
    y_train = np.array([[37.92, 138.25, 324.66, 16.28, 16.27, 16.28]])\
        .astype(theano.config.floatX)

    for _ in xrange(100):
        print f_train(x_train, y_train)


main()
```

Note that the learning rate also needs to be reduced a lot to prevent divergence.